# Ошибка в CMake в CLion с подключением библиотеки

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clion

Не удается подключить библиотеку zlib  к проекту.

**Вот такой CMake имеется**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(PcapCatalog)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set (HEADERS ethernet_frame.h icmp_packet.h ipv4_packet.h     ipv6_packet.h pcap.h tcp_segment.h udp_datagram.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES ethernet_frame.cpp icmp_packet.cpp ipv4_packet.cpp ipv6_packet.cpp
        pcap.cpp Source.cpp tcp_segment.cpp udp_datagram.cpp Source.cpp)
set (SOURCES_LIB kaitai/kaitaistream.cpp)
set(HEARERS_LIB kaitai/kaitaistream.h kaitai/kaitaistruct.h)
add_library (kaitai STATIC ${HEADERS_LIB} ${SOURCES_LIB})
include_directories(kaitai)
add_subdirectory(kaitai)
find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )
add_executable(PcapCatalog ${HEADERS} ${SOURCE_FILES})
if ( ZLIB_FOUND )
    include_directories( ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
    target_link_libraries( PcapCatalog ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} )
endif( ZLIB_FOUND )
target_link_libraries(PcapCatalog kaitai)
```

**Вот такой результат в CLion**

> libkaitai.a(kaitaistream.cpp.o): In function kaitai::kstream::process_zlib(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >):
>
> /home/cryztal/CLionProjects/PcapCatalog/kaitai/kaitaistream.cpp:456: undefined reference to inflateInit_'
>
> /home/cryztal/CLionProjects/PcapCatalog/kaitai/kaitaistream.cpp:471: undefined reference to inflate'
>
> /home/cryztal/CLionProjects/PcapCatalog/kaitai/kaitaistream.cpp:483: undefined reference to inflateEnd'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> CMakeFiles/PcapCatalog.dir/build.make:278: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «PcapCatalog»
>
> make[3]: *** [PcapCatalog] Ошибка 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели
>
> «CMakeFiles/PcapCatalog.dir/all»
>
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PcapCatalog.dir/all] Ошибка 2
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели 
>   «CMakeFiles/PcapCatalog.dir/rule»
>
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PcapCatalog.dir/rule] Ошибка 2
>
> Makefile:162: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «PcapCatalog»
>
> make: *** [PcapCatalog] Ошибка 2

Comment: Вопрос не по теме: "CLion это же jetbrains? Он платный? Сколько?"

Comment: Бесплатная студенческая лицензия)

Comment: Не дорос я еще))

Comment: тогда на степике можно взять)

Comment: 1) Курс лень проходить 2) Подписка всего лишь на 2мес

Comment: ну дело твое, конечно) но 3 месяца и обновлять можно постоянно)

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, что за библиотека kaitai, но сообщение об ошибке линкер выдаёт именно для неё, а вовсе не для PcapCatalog.

Следовательно, если ссылка inflateInit_ расположена в библиотеке zlib, то должно быть и подключение этой библиотеки к kaitai. Нечто вроде:

```
target_link_libraries(kaitai ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

Вот только с порядком этих подключений надо разобраться.